# Getting Solve::nsmet error message

Tags: equation-solving

I have the following equation:

```
Profit[Fc_] = p (T - Fs - Fc)^(rho*phi) * Fc^phi * Mc^psi - w*Fc
```

and I tried

```
Solve[D[Profit[Fc], Fc] == 0, Fc]
```

but I get the error message

> Solve::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Solve

Any suggestions?

Comment: Use `FindRoot[]` with a good guess instead.

Comment: Are you looking for a symbolic or a numeric solution?

Comment: Thanks.. I am looking for symbolic solution..I tried FindRoot.. but I am getting an error: FindRoot::fdss: Search specification Fc should be a list with 1 to 5 elements